# Converting A folder of images into a .h5 file?

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

Currently I am doing the deep learning course by Andrew NG in coursera. There they are opening the dataset of images from a `.h5` file. I would like to try the same approach for my own dataset: I want to convert a folder of images to a `.h5` file.

I tried the following, but when I open the `train_x.h5` it is showing all entries as zeros.

```
h5_train = h5py.File("train_x.h5", 'w')
h5_train.create_dataset("data_train", data=np.array(train_x))
print(h5_train)
h5_train.close()
```

Here `train_x` is an array  of `shape(270000,500)`, where first entry is the number of `pixels(300*300*3)` and second entry is number of images in the folder.

Answer (score 3):

I think that either:

- `train_x` does not contain what you expect.
- You are viewing your file incorrectly.

Your syntax seems to be completely correct. When run this example, everything works as expected:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

array = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)

archive = h5py.File('test.h5', 'w')

archive.create_dataset('/array', data=array)

archive.close()
```

We can verify that it is correct by

```
import h5py

archive = h5py.File('test.h5','r')

for key in archive:
  print(key)
  print(archive[key][...])
```

This gives what we put in:

```
array
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]
```

Note here that one can also use the graphical [HDFview](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdfview/) or the command-line tool [h5dump](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html) to inspect your file.

Finally, it is good to note a second syntax for writing:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

array = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)

archive = h5py.File('test.h5', 'w')

archive['array'] = array

archive.close()
```